# How to understand states transition table in leetcode problem 65. Valid Number

Tags: c++, numbers, dfa

#### [LeetCode 65](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/)

Please tell me how the states transition table is created, I try to debug using some input, but it is really difficult to figure it out. And why the initial state is `state 1`, `state 3, 5, 8, 9` are final states.
Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    bool isNumber(string s) {
        static vector<unordered_map<string, int>> states = {
            {},                                                    // state 0
            {{"blank", 1}, {"sign", 2}, {"digit", 3}, {"dot", 4}}, // state 1
            {{"digit", 3}, {"dot", 4}},                            // state 2
            {{"digit", 3}, {"dot", 5}, {"e", 6}, {"blank", 9}},    // state 3, final
            {{"digit", 5}},                                        // state 4
            {{"digit", 5}, {"e", 6}, {"blank", 9}},                // state 5, final
            {{"sign", 7}, {"digit",8}},                            // state 6
            {{"digit", 8}},                                        // state 7
            {{"digit", 8}, {"blank", 9}},                          // state 8, final
            {{"blank", 9}}                                         // state 9, final
        };
        int currState = 1;
        string transition;

        for(auto c : s) {
            if(c>='0' && c<='9') transition = "digit";
            else if(c=='-' || c=='+') transition = "sign";
            else if(c == ' ') transition = "blank";
            else if(c == '.') transition = "dot";
            else if(c == 'e') transition = "e";
            else return false;

            auto it = states[currState].find(transition);
            if  (it == states[currState].end()) 
                return false;
            else
                currState = it->second;
        }
        if  (currState == 3 || currState == 5 || currState == 8 || currState == 9)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string str(" -90e3   ");
    Solution sol;
    bool ret = sol.isNumber(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most people here have no idea what "leetcode problem 65" is.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a pretty complicated [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), but there are some Discussion posts, explaining how it works, such as [this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/discuss/23725/C%2B%2B-My-thought-with-DFA):

```
#include <string>

class Solution {
public:
    bool isNumber(std::string number_string) {

        while (!number_string.empty() && number_string[0] == ' ') {
            number_string.erase(number_string.begin());
        }

        while (!number_string.empty() && number_string[number_string.size() - 1] == ' ') {
            number_string.erase(number_string.end() - 1);
        }

        if (number_string.empty()) {
            return false;
        }


        int state = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < number_string.size(); index++) {
            if (number_string[index] == '+' || number_string[index] == '-') {
                if (state == 0 || state == 3) {
                    state++;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } else if (number_string[index] == '.') {
                if (state == 2) {
                    state = 7;

                } else if (state == 0 || state == 1) {
                    state = 6;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } else if (number_string[index] >= '0' && number_string[index] <= '9') {
                if (state == 1 || state == 4 || state == 6) {
                    state++;

                } else if (state == 0 || state == 3) {
                    state += 2;
                }

            } else if (number_string[index] == 'e' || number_string[index] == 'E') {
                if (state == 2 || state == 7) {
                    state = 3;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return (state == 2 || state == 5 || state == 7) ? true : false;
    }
};
```

Even though, regex is not the best way to solve algorithm problems, for this particular one, it would have been okay. For instance, this'll get accepted in python:

```
import re

class Solution:
    def isNumber(self, s):
        s = str(s).strip()
        expression = r"^[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)[Ee][+-]?\d+$|^[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)$|^[+-]?\d+$"
        match = re.match(expression, s)
        
        return True if match else False
```

However for some reason, regex gives TLE in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). See [this post](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/discuss/393355/1-regexp-solution-c%2B%2B):

```
#include <regex>
regex r(R"(^(\s*)?[-+]?(((\d{1,})(\.\d{1,})?)|(\d{1,}\.)|(\.\d{1,}))(e[-+]?\d{1,})?(\s*)?$)");
class Solution {
public:
    bool isNumber(const string& s) {
        return regex_match(s, r);
        
    }
};
```

In python, this would also simply pass:

```
class Solution:
    def isNumber(self, s):
        try:
            float(str(s).strip())
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

In Java also, this'd simply pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final boolean isNumber(String s) {
        s = s.trim();
        boolean pointSeen = false;
        boolean eSeen = false;
        boolean digitSeen = false;
        boolean digitAfterE = true;

        for (int i = 0; i != s.length(); i++) {
            if ('0' <= s.charAt(i) && s.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                digitSeen = true;
                digitAfterE = true;

            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
                if (eSeen || pointSeen) {
                    return false;
                }

                pointSeen = true;

            } else if (s.charAt(i) == 'e') {
                if (eSeen || ! digitSeen) {
                    return false;
                }

                digitAfterE = false;
                eSeen = true;

            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '-' || s.charAt(i) == '+') {
                if (i != 0 && s.charAt(i - 1) != 'e') {
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return digitSeen && digitAfterE;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.